# Cast type to va_arg return

Tags: c, casting, variadic-functions

Can i cast type to va_arg return as on example? 
As i know va_arg can't read-return char/short int types

```
if (flags->size == 0)
    u->s = (char)va_arg(pt, int);
if (flags->size == 1)
    u->s = (short int)va_arg(pt, int);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard specifies that

> The `va_arg` macro expands to an expression that has the specified type and the value of the next argument in the call.

([C2011 7.16.1.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.1p2))

The fact that such an expression resulted from expansion of a macro has no bearing on how it can be used.  In particular, when the type specified to `va_arg` is `int`, the resulting `int`-type expression can certainly be cast to other integer types, provided that `va_arg()`'s behavior is defined (roughly meaning that `int` is compatible with the promoted type of the actual argument).

So yes, you can cast the result of `va_arg()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> `va_arg` returns the current argument

So in your case it returns the value of what `pt` is pointing to as an `int`. So yes, you can cast that value.